# I need help with punctuation while using conjunctions

Tags: conjunctions

Do the two sentences below need a comma before "and"? If so, why?

1 "Juanita is brilliant and Shalimar has a pleasant personality."

2 "Use your credit cards frequently and you'll soon find yourself deep in debt."

Why is there a comma before "but"? I thought commas were not needed when the last clause is a subordinate clauses.

1 "The club never invested foolishly, but used the services of a sage investment counselor."

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Would it be wrong to omit the comma?

Answer (score 1):

Commas are usually not really about right and wrong, but about clarity and intent, and sometimes style.

---

Your first sentence is one of those that is short enough that it needs no comma:

- Juanita is brilliant and Shalimar has a pleasant personality.

However, it is also ok to use one there, especially since there is a full independent clause following the *and*:

- Juanita is brilliant, and Shalimar has a pleasant personality.

---

Your second sentence is better without the comma:

- Use your credit cards frequently and you'll soon find yourself deep in debt.

That’s because that *and* is actually acting as a conditional operator.  That sentence really means this:

- If you use your credit cards frequently then you'll soon find yourself deep in debt.

---

The third sentence is fine either way, although for a different reason:

- The club never invested foolishly but used the services of a sage investment counselor.
- The club never invested foolishly, but used the services of a sage investment counselor.

I would personally elect the version without a comma myself.

However, there are cases where you do sometimes want a comma before a coördinating conjunction even when what follows is less than an independent clause.

This is more common with *but*, perhaps because some have been taught “always” to use a comma before *but*, but is not unknown with the others.

Comment: "clarity and intent, and sometimes style" -- yay!